# Current use of tags [geotiff] and [tiff]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-excerpt

Consider tags [geotiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff) (x827) and [tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiff) (x240) with their respective tag excerpts:

[tiff]:

> Use this tag when referring to Tagged Image File Format (TIFF) **within the GIS environment**.

[geotiff]:

> GeoTIFF is a public domain metadata standard which allows georeferencing information to be embedded within a **TIFF file**.

Is there anything we could do to improve how these tags are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that the two tags warrant review, and that bringing them to a single tag would be ideal.

I agree with @Midavalo's comment that:

> All geotiff files are tiff files, but not all tiff files are geotiff.

I agree with another comment by @Midavalo that:

> I can export a map from ArcMap as a TIFF file, without it being a GeoTIFF.

I also see some questions that involve pictures in TIFF files being hyperlinked to, or loaded as attachments to, features in spatial datasets.  However, I think these have generally been tagged [hyperlink](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink) or [attachment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attachment) instead and I think that is fine to continue with that.

I propose that a simple, pragmatic and quick fix to our TIFF/GeoTIFF tagging conundrum will be to:

1. Rename [tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiff) (via a moderator merge) to be a composite tag named [geotiff-tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff-tiff), leaving [tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiff) as a synonym, and that the tag excerpt for [geotiff-tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff-tiff) be:

> Use this tag when referring to georeferenced or ungeoreferenced TIFF
>   (Tagged Image File Format) files.

2. Merge [geotiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff) (via a moderator merge) into the composite tag named [geotiff-tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff-tiff), leaving [geotiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff) as a synonym.

We have very few composite tags, and so I would not advocate creating them lightly, but in this case I think it is the cleanest fix.

Comment: Tks. How common do you think [tag:tiff] is used in that alternative sense? I ask because I found very few questions of the like.

Comment: Another question would be, aren't GeoTIFFs also suitable to use as pictures hyperlinked or attached to features? Does this type of use make it singular?

Comment: @AndreSilva My gut feel, mostly from ArcGIS Desktop questions for TIFF:GeoTIFF is about 1:3 or 1:4 but often they will have a [tag:hyperlink] or [tag:attachments] tag so maybe we should have only GeoTIFF and push the others to those tags..

Comment: @AndreSilva Although GeoTIFFs can be hyperlinked/attached I think that would be relatively rare compared to photos related to features.

Comment: I [meant](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/current-use-of-tags-geotiff-and-tiff#comment8851_4782), consider the universe of questions tagged [tag:tiff] how common do you think [tiff] is being used as an image not related to spatial data (like a photograph). Aren't those exceptions?

Comment: @AndreSilva `[tiff] hyperlink is:question` and `[tiff] attachment is:question` suggest never.  I suspect what has happened is that the questions I am thinking of are already tagged hyperlink or attachment rather than by their image format.  I'm going to revise my answer.

Comment: My concern is to pick up a tag which has a strong 'signal' (tiff being used as geotiff or wanting to be geotiff), turn it to be the 'noise' (images/photographs not related to spatial data used as attachments in databases, etc), then creating two problems just after updating the excerpt: i) having many questions incorrectly tagged (the signal); ii) having a tag once frequently used, now reserved to a subject with only a few questions (instead of use it as powerful synonym-merge).

Comment: @AndreSilva I *think* that I am aligning with your thinking now.

Comment: Note, I can export a map from ArcMap as a TIFF file, without it being a GeoTIFF.  We also have [tag:jpg] and [tag:png], for example, neither of which are spatial in nature, but like TIFF files are still used regularly.

Comment: @Midavalo maybe we do need to consider a composite tag of [tag:geotiff-tiff] as a master to the other two.

Comment: @AndreSilva I've revised my answer again so feel free to review any vote that you may have cast on it.

Comment: I had already upvoted and continue to upvote. I think this answer is even better now. Because [tiff] and [geotiff] have been used for almost the same thing, and because their concept are almost the same too I do not consider [geotiff-tiff] a composite tag, just a little bit broader tag than the former which name/excerpt will be adjusted to what we currently have in GIS SE.

Comment: PolyGeo & @AndreSilva - While I'm not a fan of [tag:geotiff-tiff], I think it would work better than having the two separate tags, and would be better than just [tag:geotiff] on its own.  I'm happy to go with that as a solution.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, because so far only me, you and Midavalo participated in the discussion and we reached a consensus. Feel free to implement it whenever you are confident moving on. Tks.

Comment: Thanks @AndreSilva - I'll try to give just a few more days for any dissenting views to emerge.  Midavalo may not have had the chance to use the merge tool as often as I have, and so should feel free to do the implementation too, if ready to do so before I get to it.

Comment: PolyGeo, is it time? What are your plans to implement [geotiff-tiff]?

Comment: @AndreSilva it's time - this has now been implemented - thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2):

I think in practice, the two tags have been used interchangebly, hence they should be synonyms.

Moreover, the tag excerpts also address a similar method of use, in which the [tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiff)'s excerpt reads: *use it within the GIS environment*, i.e., when tiff files are related to spatial data.

The greater number of questions in [geotiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotiff) suggest it is the preferred terminology, so it could be the master tag (or not, vote on Midavalo’s comment if the other way around is preferred).

I agree there are questions about using TIFF images which are not GeoTIFF and even so are related to GIS (for example: [Convert TIFF to GeoTIFF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162190/convert-tiff-to-geotiff)) but I don't think keeping the two tags separate overcome the benefits of joining them (e.g. help reducing duplicates and improve searching content).

<sub>If this answer is well received two things that could be considered/evaluated in other answers are: i) the possibility to add/adapt the [tiff] excerpt in [geotiff]; ii) given point i, the possibility to rename [geotiff] to [geotiff-tiff].</sub>

Comment: I mostly agree, except I think [tag:tiff] should be the master tag

Comment: All geotiff files are tiff files, but not all tiff files are geotiff.